# Do I need to be in calorie surplus to get stronger?

Tags: strength

I'm kinda a weak person compared to other people who are at my age (mid 20s) and I want to build some basic strength (or actually, even get stronger than an average person).

I'm in a caloric deficit right now. Can I get stronger while I'm losing weight(fat) ? Can I lift weights, do pushups, etc.. and build strength? (I barely can do even 10 pushups at this point)

What about nutrition, Do I have to take lots of proteins?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple answer: no

It's definitely good to get your proteins in for recovery and building up your muscles/physique (which definitely makes it easier to lift more). However, it's not necessary to develop for strength because strength is neural. Keep in mind you'll eventually hit a plateau but you don't have to worry about it for now.

The human body's potential is amazing. You can't do 10 push ups? Do 5 throughout the day (greasing the groove) whenever you got a break or you're about to enter a room in your house. Get a check on your nutrition (which it sounds like you're doing via caloric deficit but try to get a good mix of fats/carbs/proteins in as well). Go for a walk, hit the monkey bars in your local play ground, ease into it. Or better yet, join your local gym and hit the weights. Point is, don't get bogged down in research, move!